# Are there solitary waves in $\phi^4$ theory in 3+1 dimensions?

Tags: field-theory, topological-field-theory

In 3+1 dimensions with signature +1 -1 -1 -1,

$$ \mathcal{L}= \frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi -\phi^2/2 -\phi^4/4$$

field equation: $$\square\phi+\phi+\phi^3=0$$ (check this)

$$\square=\partial^2_t-\nabla^2$$

Note that it is not a Mexican hat. I guess this haven't been solved exactly before but, somebody have shown or discarded that there could be soliton solutions or at least solitary waves?

Comment: Your field equation is correct up to a choice of sign for the metric $\eta_{\mu \nu}.$

Comment: oh yeah, I always use signature +1 -1 -1 -1

Comment: You need the opposite sign mass term, then there are solitons.

Comment: Are you sure? I have a problem with this because I need that the asymptotic behaviour to be like $e^{-r}/r$ and if it were like you are saying it cant be possible. Or not?

Comment: How is possible a domain wall in three dimensions? As a say before I think this model havent been solved before. I know perfectly the solution in 1+1 dimensions but in 3+1 dimensions Im not clear. Please give some reference about your claim.

Comment: Sorry--- domain line--- its a wall in time. I wick rotated unconsciously.

Comment: I will not give a reference--- its easy to work out without one. I don't like citing references as there are many wrong things in them. The relevant search term is phi4 domain wall, if you need more literature.

Comment: The solution will be spherically symmetric? I was supposing that in order to obtain the asymptotic behavior. I don't know what is a domain line, you are not being clear. But I think the solution should be spherically symmetric. It isn't?

Comment: @Anthonny: I gave the solution below, but it is well known. It is the extension of the 1d solution in the other dimensions homgeneously. There are no other classical solutions that go to vacuum at long distances that stay together.

Comment: I cringe every time I see D'Alembert's operator. It looks too much like the unicode box for "no symbol". :P

Answer (score 2):

The solution for the soliton in a $\phi^4$ model is given by making a field $\phi$ which depends only on x and t, and is independent of any other spatial dimensions. This is a classical one dimensional problem.

When the mass-squared parameter is *negative*, then the soliton appears. It is the solution to the equation

$$ \partial_x^2 \phi + \phi - \phi^3 = 0 $$

Where x is rescaled to absorb $\mu^2$, and $\phi$ is rescaled to absorb $\lambda$. The solution is gotten by using a version of conservation of energy, which works here because the above is a second order differential equation, which looks just like the motion of a particle in a potential

$$ V(\phi) = {1\over 2} \phi^2 - {1\over 4} \phi^4$$

Note that this is the inverted field potential appearing in the Lagrangian. The solution for $\phi$ has a x-conservation of x-energy, because if you call x "time", then the second order equation turns into Newton's laws for a one-dimensional motion. The conserved quantity is

$$ {1\over 2} (\partial_x \phi)^2 + V(\phi) = E$$

For the soliton solution, $\phi$ should go to the vacuum solution at $x=\pm\infty$. The two vacua are the two minima of the original potential, the places where

$$ \phi - \phi^3 = 0$$

or

$$\phi = \pm 1 $$

The potential at these field values gives the energy, because the field gradient has to go to zero at infinty. This makes the x-energy 1/4 at infinity.

The conservation of x-energy then tells you the field gradient

$$ (\partial\phi(x))^2 + \phi^2 - {1\over 2} \phi^4 = 1/2 $$

or that

$$ {1\over (\phi^2-1) } (\partial_x \phi) = \pm t+C $$

or

$$ \tanh^{-1} \phi = t+C $$

Which gives the standard $\phi^4$ domain wall soliton

$$ \phi(x) = \tanh(t+C)$$

This solution is a particle in 1d (1+1), a line in 2d (2+1), a domain wall in 3d (3+1), and in general, a d-1 dimensional object in d dimensions.

Comment: Your answer is fine. You have just to change the sign before the quartic term to agree with the OP's question.

Comment: @Jon: No, the sign change is in the quadratic term. The negative mass is required for a soliton solution.

Comment: Yes, but the original question was if the equation with a plus sign admits solitons. In agreement with your assertion, I display the exact solution in this case that is **not** a soliton. My answer and yours are complimentary and fully answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give you another solution to your equation that was recently published (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4053)). The equation

$$\partial_x^2\phi+\mu_0^2\phi+\lambda\phi^3=0$$

admits the exact solution

$$\phi(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2\mu^4}{\mu_0^2 + \sqrt{\mu_0^4 + 2\lambda\mu^4}}}{\rm sn}\left(p\cdot x+\theta,\sqrt{\frac{-\mu_0^2 + \sqrt{\mu_0^4 + 2\lambda\mu^4}}{-\mu_0^2 - 
   \sqrt{\mu_0^4 + 2\lambda\mu^4}}}\right)
$$

being sn a Jacobi elliptic function, $\theta$ and $\mu$ two integration constants and provided that

$$
   p^2=\mu_0^2+\frac{\lambda\mu^4}{\mu_0^2+\sqrt{\mu_0^4+2\lambda\mu^4}}.
$$

This has the appearance of a dispersion relation and $p$ is a quasi-momentum as happens in solid state with quasi-particles in a strong interacting environment.

As pointed out before, this is not a soliton solution.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with the question?

Comment: Dear @Jon. Don't forget to disclose if you are the author of the linked paper, cf. Physics.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-do-you-cite-yourself).

Comment: Dear @Qmechanic, as you can see this is not a secret. What really matters is if an argument is correct or not.