# What are the equation of motion and the energy-momentum relation of a Lagrangian with a quartic potential?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus

From the Lagrangian $$L = -\frac{1}{2} \phi\Box \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2$$ we get the equation of motion $$\Box \phi = -m^2 \phi$$  and from it we  get that the oscillation of $\phi$ in time is $\omega = \sqrt{k^2+m^2}$.

My question is: **following the same reasoning, what are (1) the equation of motion and (2) the $\omega$ of the following Lagrangian?**

$$L = -\frac{1}{2} \phi\Box \phi - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 - \frac{1}{4} \lambda \phi ^4$$

(where $m^2<0$ and $\lambda>0$).

Comment: What do you mean "the $\omega$"? The solution to the quartic equation is not a wave, it does not have periodic solution with some $\omega$ (see e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16177/50583 for some classical solutions)

Answer (score 1):

The equations of motion can be found as usual using the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\phi} = \partial_\mu\frac{\partial L}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}$$

For $L = \frac12\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi - \frac12m^2\phi^2 -\frac14\lambda\phi^4$ this gives
$$\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi = - m^2\phi - \lambda\phi^3$$

For your second question, the quantities $\omega$ and $k$ are the Fourier frequencies corresponding to $t$ and $x$ respectively, and the relation between $\omega$ and $k$ is given by taking the Fourier transform of the equation of motion
$$(k^2 - \omega^2)\hat F[\phi]  = -m^2\hat F[\phi] - \lambda \hat F[\phi^3]$$

In the simple case without the cubic term ($\lambda = 0$) you can equate the coefficients to get $\omega^2 = m^2 + k^2$, but with the $\phi^3$ term the Fourier transform can not be expressed simply in terms of $\hat F[\phi]$ so the energy momentum relation can not be expressed independently of $\phi$: it will depend on the field.

Comment: if i specify that $m^2<0$ and that $\lambda>0$ can you tell me to what does $\omega$ correspond to?

Comment: @TrentKent6 No, you would have to specify $\phi$ as well so that you can compute the Fourier transform